# R - .csv file - extract variables

Tags: r, csv

I pulled in a large .csv file with columns such as "paid" and "description"

I am trying to figure out how to only pull the "paid" column when the "description" is Bronchitis or some other illness that is in the column.

This would be like doing a pivot table in Excel and filtering only on a certain Description and receiving all of the individual paid rows.

```
 Paid Description  val 
 $500 Bronchitis   1.5
 $3,250 'Complication of Pregnancy/Childbirth' 2.2
 $5,400 Burns 3.3
 $20.50 Bronchitis 4.4
 $24  Ashtma 1.2
```

Comment: Please provide a small example data and the expected result based on that.  What is `some other illness`?  Please be specific.  You can refer the link for how to make a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: ex data /
Paid               Description
$500               Bronchitis
$3,250            Complication of Pregnancy/Childbirth
$5,400               Burns
$20.50              Bronchitis

I am trying to break out bronchitis so it would show as 
Paid               Description
$500               Bronchitis
$20.50              Bronchitis

And then I could just to data analysis on individual descriptions

Comment: It is not easy to get the correct format from the comment.  Please use the edit button in your post and update it

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `df`, `df.subset = df[df$description %in% c("Bronchitis","Asthma","COPD"), c("paid","description")]`. Just include whatever diseases are of interest.

Comment: Sounds like Package "readr" and functions "dplyr::filter" and "dplyr::select" might help.

Comment: df[desc=="a",c("paid")]

Comment: The df subset got it to work, thanks eipi10 and everyone else!

Comment: Using this type of code df.subset = df[df$description %in% c("Bronchitis","Asthma","COPD"), c("paid","description")]

How would I further break it down by Description AND Paid, ex/ Bronchitis with Paid > $500

Answer (score 1):

If your data is

```
paid <- c(300,200,150)
desc <- c("bronchitis","headache","broken.leg")
df <- data.frame(paid, desc)
```

Try

```
df[desc=="bronchitis",c("paid")]

# the argument ahead of the comma filters the row,
# the argument after the comma refers to the column

# > df[desc=="bronchitis",c("paid")]
# [1] 300
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(desc=="bronchitis") %>% select(paid)

# filter refers to the row condition
# select filters the output column(s)


# > df %>% filter(desc=="bronchitis") %>% select(paid)
#   paid
# 1  300
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setkey(setDT(df1), Description)[.('Bronchitis'),'Paid', with=FALSE]
#    Paid
#1:   $500
#2: $20.50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ex = c("Description", "Bronchitis",
"Complication of Pregnancy/Childbirth", 
"Burns", "Bronchitis", "Ashtma"), data = c("val", "1.5", "2.2", 
"3.3", "4.4", "1.2")), .Names = c("ex", "data"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("Paid", "$500", "$3,250", "$5,400", "$20.50", "$24"))
```